# Finding the Mean, Variance, and Probability of a Poisson Model

Tags: probability

I've tried to solve the following homework question, but I am not sure if I am approaching it correctly.

Here is the question (it consists of several part, but once I understand the first two I should be able to do the rest):

The number of hurricanes coming within 250 miles of Honolulu has been modeled according to a Poisson process with a mean of 0.45 per year.

> a) Find the mean and variance of the time between successive hurricanes coming within 250 miles of Honolulu.

My attempt:

Let $X$ be the length of time in months between two successive hurricanes. Since the mean of an exponential function is $E[X]=\lambda$, we need to find lambda. Also, since the model is a Poisson process the mean, $0.45$, is equal to $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ Therefore, The length of time between two successive hurricanes is given by$\frac{1}{\lambda}=0.45$ which means that $\lambda=\frac{1}{0.45}=\frac{20}{9}\approx2.22$. Therefore, $E[X]\approx2.22$. The variance of an exponential function is $Var(X)=\lambda^2=(\frac{20}{9})^2\approx 4.94$
(I'm hoping I did this correctly.)

> b) Given that a hurricane has just occurred, what is the probability that it will be less than 3 months until the next hurricane.

This one is giving me a hard time, because I'm not sure how to represent the fact that a hurricane has just occurred, but this is how I set it up. Since $X$ is the number of months between hurricanes and one has just occurred, is this simply: $$P(X\lt3)=\int_0^3 0.45e^{(-x/0.45)}dx=1-e^{-20/3}?$$

I'm hoping that this was the correct approach to both parts, and any  input will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers to the first question are correct. I will use what I hope is standard terminology in your course.

First, I would use the year as the unit of time. The number $H$ of hurricanes in a year has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=0.45$.  It follows that the waiting time $X$ (**in years**) between consecutive hurricanes has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$. So $X$ has density function $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ (for $x\gt 0$).

The mean of an exponential with parameter $\lambda$ is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and the variance is $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$. These are the numbers you obtained.

The probability that the waiting time between consecutive hurricanes is less than $3$ months ($1/4$ of a year) is
$$\int_0^{1/4}(0.45)e^{-0.45 x}\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get $1-e^{-(0.45)(1/4)}$.

**Remark:** If you really want to, you can use months as a unit. But then the appropriate $\lambda$ for the Poisson, and the exponential, is $(0.45)/12$.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was wondering whether or not I should use months or years. Your remark is also helpful, but I think I will stick to using years. Can I ask you another related question?

Comment: Sure, no problem, just ask. The only problem is that it is difficult to answer properly in comments, I tend to wordiness!

Comment: Another part to the question says that if the last hurricane was 6 months ago what is the probability that it will be at least another 6 months until a hurricane? Since the exponential distribution is "memoryless" does this reduce to finding $P(X\ge 1/2)$?

Comment: You have it exactly right.

Comment: Thanks so very much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome.